# can any one tell me why "X509_verify " function returns -1 .?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, signature

I am using openssl 0.9.8g to validate the certificate signature . The API  "X509_verify " returns 0/1 according to the document .  but i am getting -1 as return value . why i am getting -1 as return value  ..?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the algorithms details ..
call these functions to add the algorithm list

```
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

Return -1 because it is not able to find the Algorithm obj_ID .